# shotgun gem bug 'cannot load such file -- thin'

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, thin, shotgun

I'm using shotgun to serve my Sinatra project on Ubuntu development machine. And when I'm starting shotgun with -d (debug), it returns me

```
Exception `LoadError' at /home/askhat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55 - cannot load such file -- thin
Exception `LoadError' at /home/askhat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:169 - LoadError
```

But thin gem is installed. Actually shotgun works properly with this error. There is no problem, just interesting why it's appends?

Answer (score 0):

do you have a `Gemfile` in your app? usually it should be enough to add `thin` to `Gemfile` as RVM uses `rubygems-bundler` gem which automatically assumes `bundle exec` context for binaries that are installed from gems via `Gemfile`.

Comment: Yes I have, and _thin_ is listed in Gemfile

Comment: I missed to ask is `shotgun` listed in Gemfile?

Comment: so I assume `bundle exec shotgun` also fails?